# Extract value from a dynamic variable in python?

Tags: python, class, pointers

My question refers to the example posted [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-42-changing-class-members-python/)

In the script below, an example of a dynamic variable

```
class CSStudent:
    stream = 'cse'     # Class Variable
    def __init__(self, name, roll):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = roll

# New object for further implementation
a = CSStudent("check", 3) #(1): value of interest !!!!!!
print("a.stream =", a.stream) 

# Correct way to change the value of class variable
CSStudent.stream = "mec"
print("\nClass variable changes to mec")

# New object for further implementation
b = CSStudent("carter", 4)

print("\nValue of variable steam for each object")
print("a.stream =", a.stream)
print("b.stream =", b.stream)
```

I would like to keep the value of `a = CSStudent("check", 3)` before the change to the class is affected.

I know that one way is to initialize the class before declaring every value. However, I am not interested in this method since for classes that need a longer setup, this may be time consuming.

Is there a python functionality to take a "snap-shot" of the values before the class is changed?

Comment: This isn't Python 3.x syntax. In Python 3 `print` is a function, not a statement, the arguments have to be in parentheses.

Comment: There isn't a separate value of `stream` for each object. It's a class variable that all the class instances share. If you want it to be specific to each object, make it an instance variable.

Comment: @Bramar I am looking more for a way that does not require me to modify the class definition.

Comment: Then you can't do it. There's no way for `a.stream` to be different from `b.stream` when `stream` is a class variable.

Comment: @Barmar So, let's say my only option in this case is to record the value of 'a.stream' into an external .csv file? (because the csv file will remain static) I do not mind that 'a.stream' changes its value. However, I want to record its value and that the record will remain static.

Comment: Just put it in a variable. `saved_stream = a.stream`

Comment: @Barmar Ok I see, it does do the trick, I thought I have found an algorithm that matches what exactly happens in mine. I have a weird behavior where ``saved_stream`` changes similarly to ``a.stream``. I guess I should find a better representation of my issue. Thank you though!

Comment: If `stream` is a mutable object like a list, you'll need to make a copy of it, e.g. `saved_stream = a.stream.copy()`

Comment: @Barmar Amazing, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!